# error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::thread' issue in forwarding function pointer to thread

Tags: c++11

I am facing an issue in forwarding a callable object (function pointer) to a 
    thread. 
    Here is an example code trying achieve.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>                   

using namespace std;

void my_func(int x, int y, int z){
    cout << "X: " << x << "\tY: " << y << "\tZ "<<z << endl;
}

template <typename T, typename ...  Args>
void my_thread(T func, Args&&... args){
    // Do something
    func(forward<Args&&>(args)...);
}

template <typename T, typename ...  Args>
void call_thread(T func,  Args&& ... args){
     // Do something
    thread t1(my_thread, func, forward<Args&&>(args)...);
    t1.detach();
}

int main()
{
    call_thread(my_func, 2,5,6);
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
In instantiation of 'void call_thread(T, Args&& ...) [with T = void (*)(int, int, int); Args = {int, int, int}]':
required from here

error: no matching function for call to 'std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>, void (*&)(int, int, int), int, int, int)'
    thread t1(my_thread, func, forward<Args&&>(args)...);
                                                       ^
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `my_thread`?

Comment: In my real code my thread is member funtion of class which does some initialization before creating thread.

Answer (score 0):

In the declaration statement

```
thread t1(my_thread, func, forward<Args&&>(args)...);
```

since `my_thread` is the name of a function template, it's essentially a large set of different functions.  But to instantiate the `std::thread` constructor and create the `std::thread`, the compiler needs to choose just one specialization of `my_thread` and the `std::thread` constructor.  Since the `thread` constructor is set up to take any callable type at all as the first argument, there isn't a direct relationship between the callable and the arguments that would help force that into one type, and the compiler can't figure it out on its own.

So specify the correct `my_thread` specialization:

```
thread t1(my_thread<T, Args...>, func, forward<Args&&>(args)...);
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, it's not a good idea to initialize std::thread in a function where it goes out of scope immediately. It's better to keep track of the std::thread object. Anyway, your my_thread() function seems unnecessary to me, since call_thread() does the calling of a thread function which is passed into it (func). Below code works when compiled with `-lpthread` on Arch Linux x86_64:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>  
#include <utility>                 

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

void my_func(int x, int y, int z){
    std::cout << "X: " << x << "\tY: " << y << "\tZ "<<z << std::endl;
}

template <typename T, typename ...  Args>
void call_thread(T&& func, Args&& ... args) {
     // Do something
    std::thread t1(std::forward<T>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    t1.detach();
}

int main() {
    call_thread(my_func, 2, 5, 6);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s);
    return 0;
}
```

By the way, you need the thread sleep at the end; otherwise your program will reach to `return 0` and exit, before my_func() prints out the values!